# How to insert an image into the stroke

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

I would like to insert an image into the stroke (border) of a shape. I remember I did it once but can not seem to repeat it. I only want to have the image in the border, not in the center of the image like it is currently doing.

I am using InDesign.

Answer (score 3):

1. Make a shape with the desired stroke width in Illustrator:

[image]

2. Select the shape and access the menu `Object > Expand...`:

[image]

3. In the Expand options box, select the Stroke as the part of the graphic you'd like to outline:

[image]

4. Copy/Paste your new shape into InDesign
5. Import your border image into the InDesign file and simply Copy `Command + C`, then select your border shape and Paste Into `Command + Option + V`:

[image]

[image]

6. Double-click the link icon in the shape's top left corner to move the image around to the desired location.